# How can I save the date in the firestore with input type of date?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've noticed that I can save in the firestore the other inputs of address and names but delivery date is not included when it is saved. How can I save it on the firestore?

```
 <input
    id="date"
    type="date"
    onChange={(e) => setDeliveryDate(e.target.value)}
  />
```

And this is how I save the data in the firestore:

```
try {
      firestore.collection("orders").add({
        order,
        displayName: displayName,
        address: address,
        deliveryDate: deliveryDate
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide more code about what does the setDeliverydate function and the full input code as well? Did you try converting the date to a string?

Answer (score 0):

simply convert the date from js to Timestamp

```
import  firebase from 'firebase'
import  '@firebase/firestore'

const delivery_date_TimeStamp =firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(DeliveryDate))
```

then upload to firstore

```
firestore.colection('someCollections').add({
   delivery_date:delivery_date_timeStamp 
})
```

Comment: why does it say ": Cannot read property 'fromDate' of undefined"

Comment: can you show me how your importing ```firestore```

Comment: no I meant the import statement at top `` import firestre form ...``

Comment: just importing firestore from my own file. It's bascially firestore = firebase.firestore()

Comment: check my edited answer to see how I'm importing firestone

Comment: it still says that fromDate is undefined

Comment: hmmm weird probably your using a different implementation , do you have this project on GitHub so I can see the larger picture